# Check if service exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

What can I write in my batch to check if a service exists? Right now if I run a `net stop` and the service doesn't exist my batch just continue to the next one. I would like it to check and if it exists it runs the `net stop` otherwise it doesn't.

```
for %%S in ("service1" "service2" "service3") do (
 REM Put your code you want to execute here
 REM For example, the following line
 net stop"%%~S"
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query service status with `sc.exe` and check `ERRORLEVEL` after that:

```
for %%S in ("service1" "service2" "service3") do (
    sc query %%S > nul
    if ERRORLEVEL 0 (sc stop "%%~S")
)
```

Comment: @user1423277 Extra quotes slipped in, I've fixed it, try again.

Comment: One problem is that if it is stopped it get error anyway